# I have a json file with 1500 keys, whats the best way to iterate through them?

Tags: python, json, recursion

Each key has a list of strings in them that I use to compare to another list. The dictionary is very nested so I use a recursive function to get the data of each key.

But it takes a long time to get through the entire list. Is there a faster way?

This is the code:

```
def get_industry(industry_data, industry_category): category_list = list()

    for category in industry_category:
        for key, item in category.items():
            r = re.compile('|'.join([r'\b%s\b' % porter.stem("".join(w.split())) for w in item['key_list']]), flags=re.I)
            words_found = r.findall(industry_data)
            if words_found:
                category_list.extend([key])
                new_list = get_industry(' '.join(words_found), item["Subcategories"])
                category_list.extend(new_list)

    return category_list
```

This is an example of a JSON file.

```
[
  {
    "Agriculture": {
      "Subcategories": [
        {
          "Fruits ": {
            "Subcategories": [
              {
                "Fresh Fruits": {
                  "Subcategories": [
                    {
                      "Apricots": {
                        "Subcategories": [],
                        "key_list": [
                          "Apricots"
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "Tamarinds": {
                        "Subcategories": [],
                        "key_list": [
                          "Tamarinds"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  "key_list": [
                    "loganberries",
                    "medlars"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ],
            "key_list": [
              "lemons",
              "tangelos"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "Vegetables ": {
            "Subcategories": [
              {
                "Beetroot": {
                  "Subcategories": [],
                  "key_list": [
                    "Beetroot"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "Wasabi": {
                  "Subcategories": [],
                  "key_list": [
                    "Wasabi"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ],
            "key_list": [
              "kohlrabies",
              "wasabi "
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "key_list": [
        "wasabi",
        "batatas"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

This is an example of a list I want it compared with.

```
["lemons","wasabi","washroom","machine","grapefruit","about","city"]
```

The answer should return this list:
    ["Agriculture","Vegetables","Wasabi"]

In order to compare list to list and return category, it takes about 3-5 seconds to finish the operation. I heard that using Pandas will significantly increase the speed.

Comment: can you show the list you are trying to compare it with?

Comment: add a list to compare it with example.

Comment: please specify the comparison list with respect to the above json you provided

Comment: how long is "a long time"?

Comment: long is more than a second. Changed json and added an example result.

Comment: A couple of things occur to me: find out whether the part of your algorithm taking up the time is the recursive iteration or the regex matching combined with word stem calculation; if it is the latter, then can you pre-calculate canonical forms for your matching words? You also seem to need to invert your dictionary: make the key_list the top key. Pandas can do the equivalent of this (pivot the multidimensional table), but if your industry_data dict is not too large, then can you do it in native Python?

Comment: The key question here is the structure of your data. If you can't change the input format of  the json data, try to transform it in to another structure that supports searching better than by iterating recursively through it. Possible solution here may be flattening out the structure or as @xnx suggested inverting the dictionary.